# How to get the most close item from a list times

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a list of Property class having Start and End time as a properties
like :  `List<PropSchedules>`

```
PropSchedules   
{  
 DateTime StartTime,  
 DateTime EndTime  
}
```

values are like :

```
Starttime   EndTime
07:00       09:00
11:00       14:00
15:00       20:00
```

now I have a time, and I want to know which one is lowest greater starttime.

Like if I have a time say, 10:00 then 2nd item is lowest greater.

So, any one have some shortcut to get the same or I have to do the loop and check each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering a class PropSchedules

```
class PropSchedules
{
    public DateTime StartTime;
    public DateTime EndTime;
}
```

and a list of PropSchedules

```
List<PropSchedules> listSchedules;
```

and a reference date named start :

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now; // for example
```

then you can find the next PropSchedules with :

```
PropSchedules next = listSchedules.Where(s => s.StartTime > start).OrderBy(s => s.StartTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

next can be null if there is no value lower greatest

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
your_list.Where(x => x.Starttime > XXXX).Min(. . .)
```

Comment: Any reason not to fill in the lambda in the `Min` method call?

Comment: @Chris not exactly, do not 100% remember about params.

Answer (score 2):

Provided I understand the problem, something like this?

```
List<PropSchedules> propSchedules = // ...
DateTime Time = // ...

var closest = propSchedules
    .Where(e => e.StartTime > Time)
    .Select(e => e.StartTime)
    .Min();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are inserting and removing values a lot, you could use a  [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28VS.85%29.aspx), or [SortedDictonary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28VS.85%29.aspx) to make sure things are in order.

Comment: SortedList is for key value but i have more properties more than Start and EndTime, sorry i have not mention in question